# Comparison between dates in C# application

Tags: c#, .net, date, datetime, compare

I have an asp.net application in which i have these three dates:

now = `08-10-13 15:56:19`

cloture1 = `01-10-13 00:00:00`

cloture2= `01-01-50 00:00:00`

The format of dates is `DD-MM-YY HH:MM:SS`. the problem is that the function `DateTime.Compare()` gives me the same result ie

`DateTime.Compare(now,cloture1) > 0` and  `DateTime.Compare(now,cloture2) > 0`.

So what is the reasons of this problem? How can i fix my snippet?

Comment: Now would always be greater than both of those. Am I missing something?

Comment: no why?? look at the date's format

Comment: @neoistheone, cloture2 is in the 2050, if I am reading correctly.

Comment: @BolucPapuccuoglu, I'm pretty sure that the `50` is being interpreted as `1950`.

Comment: @neoistheone: Yes, that is origin of the OP's problem. But his intent is to set cloture2 as a date is 2050, if I am sensing correctly.

Comment: > The format of dates is DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS
Is the "08-10-13 15:56:19", for example, has a 4-digit year?

Comment: @Lamloumi, it would be helpful if you posted the code when you are setting the values for cloture1 and cloture2

Comment: why `50` is interpreted as `1950` but `13` is interpreted as `2013`!!!!!!

Comment: Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#yySpecifier and also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.twodigityearmax.aspx. There is a property which decides which to digit years are 2000 and which are 1900

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`The "yy" Custom Format Specifier`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#yySpecifier)

> In a parsing operation, a two-digit year that is parsed using the "yy"
>   custom format specifier is interpreted based on the
>   `Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax` property of the format provider's current
>   calendar.
>
> In a parsing operation, a two-digit year that is parsed using the "yy"
>   custom format specifier is interpreted based on the
>   Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax property of the format provider's current
>   calendar. The following example parses the string representation of a
>   date that **has a two-digit year by using the default Gregorian calendar
>   of the en-US culture.**

From [`GregorianCalendar.TwoDigitYearMax`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.gregoriancalendar.twodigityearmax.aspx)

> **This property allows a 2-digit year to be properly translated to a
>   4-digit year. For example, if this property is set to 2029, the
>   100-year range is from 1930 to 2029. Therefore, a 2-digit value of 30
>   is interpreted as 1930, while a 2-digit value of 29 is interpreted as
>   2029.**
>
> Your application should set this value to 99 to indicate that 2-digit
>   years are to be taken literally. For example, if this property is set
>   to 99, the 100-year range is from 0 (not a valid value for most
>   calendars) to 99. Therefore, a 2-digit value of 30 is interpreted as
>   30.

Even when you decompile `GregorianCalendar.TwoDigitYearMax` property, you can see yourself;

```
public override int TwoDigitYearMax
{
  get
  {
    if (this.twoDigitYearMax == -1)
      this.twoDigitYearMax = Calendar.GetSystemTwoDigitYearSetting(this.ID, 2029);
    return this.twoDigitYearMax;
  }
```

[`Boluc's answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19250113/447156) is completely right. I want to point also your format part.

You can't format two digit year with `YYYY` format. You need to use `yy` format which allows two digit formatting.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("01-01-50 00:00:00", "dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Prints

```
01.01.1950 00:00:00
```

Here a <kbd>[`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/OIeKtT)</kbd>.

Check out for more informations from [`Custom Date and Time Format Strings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

The problem is your program most probably interpreting cloture2 as 1950, not 2050.
Because you have not posted the code in which you set cloture2, I cannot offer a concrete solution, but the best I can offer is that you use 01-10-2050 explicitly in your code.

Comment: Agreed, you are using the date time format DD-MM-YYYY, but you are only passing in DD-MM-YY. Remember all the publicity about the "millennium bug"? that was because people were using YY not YYYY for their dates.

Comment: why `50` is interpreted as `1950` but `13` is interpreted as `2013`?

Comment: Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#yySpecifier and also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.twodigityearmax.aspx. There is a property which decides which two digit years are 2000 and which are 1900

Answer (score 1):

If `now` is later than `cloture1` then the returned value will be 1 (or Greater than Zero).

The code you have supplied along with the example dates seems to work fine in reference to the MSDN article for `DateTime.Compare` method.

Please check the following link for more information on the `DateTime.Compare` method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare.aspx

If you believe that your code is still incorrect please elaborate on your question.